# java ,Properly using Static variables to prevent deadlock - Synchronizing

Tags: java, android, concurrency, synchronized, android-sqlite

I am new to android programming and 've not thoroughly studied java before . I am really confused on how to use `synchronized` to ensure thread safety on `static variables` :

I usually create a class named `Utils` which has some `static functions` which are most of the time needed by all my other classes. Is this the correct way of keeping repetitive code out of my classes.

I always suffer from a problem with using Databases. When I create sqliteHelper class for certain Database and try to manage that database from say an Activity and a Background service , I usually get
into trouble. If I use local objects of helper class , I am maximum prone to getting into deadlocking of database when both the helper objects try to acquire write lock together.

For getting out of this trouble , I create a `static` instance of the helper class in my `utils` class. Now for performing any operation on database my activity and my service do the following thing :

```
   public class Utils{
          public static MDatabaseHelper mHelper;
          public static void instantiateHelper(Context context){
          if(mHelper==null)
                mHelper=new MDatabaseHelper(context);

           }
    } 



    public class mActivity extends Activity{
     public void insert some item in database(final Item item)   // this method is called in the Activity at some time
     (new Thread(){
         @Override public void run(){
         Utils.instantiateHelper(getBaseContext());
         mHelper.insertItem(item); }
        }).start();
     }




 public class mService extends Service{
         public void insert some item in database(final Item item)    // this method is called in the service at some time
          (new Thread(){
           @Override public void run{
             Utils.instantiateHelper(getBaseContext());
             mHelper.insertItem(item); }
        }).start();
     }
```

Now what if both the service and the activity try to insert the item together. I oftentimes get into this situation and an error occurs .
To avoid this I use this workaround :

I put the insert operation in a try block and on failure I wait for random time and try again

```
    public void insertSomeItemInDatabase(final Item item)
     (new Thread(){
          @Override public void run(){
              int i=0;
              Random rand=new Random();
                 while(true){
                  if(i>10)
                    return;
                  try{ 
                     Utils.instantiateHelper(getBaseContext());
                     mHelper.insertItem(item);
                     break;
                     }catch(Exception e){
                      i++;
                           try{
                              Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(1000));
                               }catch(Exception e){}
                      }

                      }
          } 
          }
        }).start();
     }
```

I know this is the **Worst** method of synchronizing but since I am so new to `java` can any one please explain how to use `synchronized` in this Scenario .

Thank You

Comment: why isn't your insertSomeItemInDatabase synchronized?

Comment: FYI: Your approach is a common method in network protocols. It is somewhat similar to the [Aloha Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALOHA_protocol#The_ALOHA_protocol). You might want to apply [exponantial back off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) if you want to stick with this approach.

Comment: I do not know much about synchronizing static variable . A code snippet and explanation will be a great help @njzk2

Comment: what do you mean by "to getting into deadlocking of database when both the helper objects try to acquire write lock together". If you have just one lock, there's no chance to get deadlock situation, you need more than one lock for that.

Comment: there is nothing static to it. simply put synchronized in the declaration of your insertItem method. It means that only one thread can access it at once, others being queued and waiting.

Comment: Hey friend, update your Location and some bio on your profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all your need is to create **Application Class**

**[1]** All those variables you have taken in Util, which are used in about all other class, can be taken in this Application class. So these variables will be available to all other classes.

**[2]** Create Singelton instance of **Appliction class**. Just Google about it.

**[3]** Also create Singleton of DataBaseHelper(if possible and can apply), so, single instance helps you every where.

---

Application Class is Global class in android, so you can use it to store and access all Global-Data. e.g. :

```
public class AppData extends Application {

    public static AppData appData;

    public int currentUserId; // etc.

    //Const.
    public AppData() {
        appData = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
            SPF_NAME, 0);

        pathToSDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("Path : " + pathToSDCard);
       //etc.
    }

 //    MOST IMP  FOR GETTIN SINGELTON INSTANCE     <<<---<<<---<<<---
    public static AppData getAppData() {
        return appData;
    }
}
```

**HOW TO USE IT,  SEE THIS**

```
class ABC extends Activity {
    AppData appData;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xyz);

        appData = AppData.getAppData();
        ...........
        ...........

        appData.VARIABLE_NAME...
    }
}
```

**One thing more. In AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
    ...
    ...
<application             //   In Application Tag
        android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.AppData"  //  <<  Add here class name in which you have extended Application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    ...
    ...
```