# Global Variables Android

Tags: android, eclipse, global-variables

I am new to Android app development and would like a little information on global variables. I have done a lot of searching and I understand that in the class files you can declare a global variable(correct me if I'm wrong). I have taken a look at a lot of posts including [Android - Global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658980/android-global-variables) . They have not helped me to understand what I would like to know. My goal is to be able to create variables that will change and remain changed after the app has been terminated. The idea that I have is that I would like to have a main page that then branches to a bunch of other pages and have a global variable that saves what page your are currently visiting so that when you resume you can press a button labeled continue and it will bring you back to the page that you were previously on. If there is a better way than global variables, I am open to alternatives, thanks in advance!

Comment: [SEE THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744094/java-properly-using-static-variables-to-prevent-deadlock-synchronizing/12744214#12744214)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have variables - global or otherwise - persist after the app has been terminated unless you write them to a permanent storage. In Android this can be done with an ObjectOutputStream to write an object to the filesystem or SharedPreferences, which save key/value pairs for retrieval. You will have to save and set your variables when you need them.

But you shouldn't do global variables anyway.

Comment: Ok, could you give me an example of how the ObjectOutputStream works? or SharedPreferences? I had been trying to figure out how they worked and visited many pages but to no avail. I couldn't successfully write data then open it again, if you could show me an example I would really appreciate it!

Comment: you should read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). basically you call `getSharedPreferences(name, mode)` to get a SharedPreferences object. then you call `getXXXX(key, default)` to get a setting. to put a setting into the preferences file, use `pref.edit().putXXXX(key, value).commit()`

Answer (score 6):

You can use SharedPreferences to do that. In your activity, use:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.edit().putString("lastPage","mainPage").commit;
```

To read your saved data, use:

```
String lastPage = preferences.getString("lastPage");
```

Read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html to know the types that you can store.